# Proof by induction to show that $5^n \geq 4n+1 $ for all natural numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

I let my base step be $n=1$,
$5^1 \geq 4(1) + 1$ is true.
We can now assume that it is true for some number $n = k$ where $k$ is a natural number.
We wish to show the claim is still true for $n = k+1$.
I do not know how to complete the inductive step.

Comment: multiply  both sides of the assumption with 5

Comment: Hint: $5^{k+1}=5.5^k $, can you complete?

Comment: Does the binomial theorem count as induction? If so, $5^n=(1+4)^n=4^0\binom{n}{0}+4^1\binom{n}{1}+4^2\binom{n}{2}+\cdots \ge 1+4n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is true for $n=k$, then we have $$5^k \geq 4k+1,$$ so we can multiply both sides by 5 to get $$5^{k+1} \geq 5(4k+1) \geq 4(k+1)+1,$$ completing the proof by induction.

Answer (score 1):

$5^{k+1}=5\cdot 5^k\ge 5(4k+1)=16k+4k+5\ge4k+5=4(k+1)+1$